# Ruby gems with C extensions not building in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, docker, heroku, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to base a `Dockerfile` off of Heroku's new `heroku/heroku:18` image (which uses Ubuntu 18.04) and running into some issues that I didn't have in their very old `heroku/cedar:14` base image, I believe due to them having [different preinstalled packages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages). (I updated the base image to [`heroku/heroku:18`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack) because I want to use the [`webpacker`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gem and in Cedar-14 I was getting: `Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.25`. If there's an easy way to install a newer Node in the older base image I'd love to hear it!)

My problem is that no gems with C extensions (like `puma`, `pg`, `msgpack`, etc. etc.) install successfully with this new base Docker image. The error messages vary slightly from gem to gem but all generally say:

```
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

Various GitHub issues with similar problems have had me try:

- `apt-get install`ing:

  - `build-essential`
  - `libpq-dev`
  - `libssl-dev`
  - `openssl`
  - `libssl1.0-dev`
  - `gcc`
  - `gcc-5`
  - `automake`
  - `make`
- Using `heroku/heroku:18-build` instead of `heroku/heroku:18`

None of these solutions solves the issue.

For reference, here are the relevant parts of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM heroku/heroku:18

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs --no-recommends

RUN (mkdir -p /ruby && cd /ruby && curl https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.5.0.tgz -s -o - | tar xzf - --no-same-owner)

ENV GEM_HOME=/ruby/gems GEM_PATH=/ruby/gems

RUN gem install bundler

RUN bundle install
```